# How to debug DNS not working for Docker Container?

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, centos7

I am beginning to work with Docker containers and have a problem with DNS resolution from a container.
There seem to be many questions on StackOverflow similar to this problem, but I'm not able to solve it.

I'm on CentOS Linux 7.7.1908 Host.
I've built a new container on this machine and and add it to an existing docker-compose.yml file.

But something seems to be missing in my container -- DNS isn't working within it.
Other containers started from docker-compose don't have this problem.

In docker-compose, the start of my new container and a DNS-working existing container seem the same, something like the following:

```
existingcontainer:
    image: johnson/job1:2.1.0
    environment:
        JAVA_OPTS: " -Xms256m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
        - 8090:8090

newcontainer:
    image: johnson/job2:1.0.0
    environment:
        JAVA_OPTS: " -Xms256m -Xmx512m"
    ports:
        - 8091:8090
```

The containers start up and the functionality within them both work fine, except within the new container DNS doesn't work.

```
docker container exec existingcontainer_1 ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.12.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
...

docker container exec newcontainer_1 ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known

docker container exec newcontainer_1 ping 172.217.12.238
PING google.com (172.217.12.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
...
```

So, DNS resolution isn't working with the newcontainer, but it is possible to access the internet via an IP address.  My conclusion is that some configuration is missing in the container.

```
docker container exec existingcontainer_1 cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1   localhost ip6-localhost
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.15  2a51cabe0eaf

docker container exec newcontainer_1 cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1   localhost ip6-localhost
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.11  0c73f229b689

docker container exec existingcontainer_1 cat /etc/resolv.conf
search ec2.internal
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots::0

docker container exec newcontainer_1 cat /etc/resolv.conf
search ec2.internal
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots::0
```

The networking configurations for DNS look the same.
Based on some articles, I added the following ExecStart setting in the docker.service file to force a DNS server and then restarted docker and the docker-compose containers:

```
--dns 8.8.8.8
```

But I see the same behavior after doing that -- DNS doesn't work on the new container.  Also, since DNS was already working in some containers, but not the new one, so I think the right fix is not a global one like that -- it seems like a change is needed to the new container.

To do troubleshooting on the container, I also found that a number of standard utilities don't seem to be available in the container environment, like netstat and iptables.  I could probably just copy these from the Host to the container?

How best to debug this?

Comment: what's the base Docker image for `johnson/job2:1.0.0`?

Comment: It is the same as for johnson/job1.  It includes an java environment.

Comment: have you tried running something like `nslookup example.com 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: I have but I found that nslookup isn't in the container (this utility files also aren't in the container that works).  I am going to try to copy some of those bin utilities from the Host.

Comment: If you can still connect to the internet with an IP address (e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8`) then it's almost for certain an issue with your DNS config.

Comment: Yes.  I can ping by IP OK, and 8.8.8.8 works OK.  I do think the problem is DNS related -- but I don't know how to fix it.  I tried copying over /bin/nslookup from the Host to the container but ran into problems when also trying to copy of the dependent lib files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208812/discussion-between-kimbo-and-george-hernando).

Answer (score 2):

I've got into similar issue with Centos 8. Looks like there is a conflict between firewalld and docker. here is one [reference](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-docker-on-centos-8). I disabled firewalld and that allowed DNS findings in the containers. It doesn't seem to be a good solution though. Need to get to the bottom of it

....

The following [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/987686/no-network-connectivity-to-from-docker-ce-container-on-centos-8) resolves the issue.

Changes made to centos 8 firewall override iptables configuration and thus breaks docker networking. It requires enabling masquerade manually.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-masquerade --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
systemctl restart docker
```

that solved the issue for me

Comment: thank you - this issue happened after rebooting my ec2 host.